# Log request/responses bodies with http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, http-proxy-middleware

I'm using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) to implement a transparent proxy.

I'd like to do request/response inspection. I mean, I'd like to print in a text file request/responses that go through the proxy whithout do any modifying on them.

Up to now, what I'm using is something like that (simplified version):

```
app.use('/proxy/:service/', proxy({
        pathRewrite: function(path, req){
            ...
        },
        router: function(req) {
            ...
        },
        onProxyRes: function(proxyRes, req, res) {
            log("Req URL: " + req.originalUrl);
            log("Response status code: " + proxyRes.statusCode);
        }
}));
```

(`log()` is a helper function that uses a string as input and prints it is my log file)

Thus, basically I'm using `onProxyRes` to intercept the response and do logging at that point. The problem is that I have been only able to make it work for things like URL, status code, headers, etc. but I haven't find the payload body in `req` and/or `resProxy` objects.

I have read about how to get the `res` body [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/97). However, it seems to be complex  solution (needs to set a `data` event handler). And it doesn't cover the `req` body, as far as I understand.

Any hint/help/reference is hightly appreciated, please. Not sure if even using `onProxyRes` is the best way of implementing this, maybe the library provides some functionality to cover the request/response case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use latest express version, this will work.

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/proxy/:service/', proxy({
        onProxyRes: function(proxyRes, req, res) {
            log("Req URL: " + req.originalUrl);
            log("Response status code: " + proxyRes.statusCode);
        }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `req.body`, you have to use a library to get it (or build it out of the stream yourself). I recommend [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I have had a look to the link to body-parser, but the way of using it in onProxyRes is not straighforward to me... Do you have any sample code or link, please?